# How to generalize the determinant as function

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, determinant

Hi I was asked to show that for any vector space $V$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$ of arbitrary dimension $n$ that if we fix some basis $\beta=\{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$ that there is a unique function

$D_\beta : V \times \cdots \times V \to \mathbb{F}$ that will satisfy the three properties,

$D_\beta(v_1,\ldots,v_n)=0$ if some $v_i=v_j, i \neq j$

$D_\beta$ is linear in each factor and

$D_\beta(w_1,\ldots,w_n)=1$

Moreover, I want to be able to prove some things using this.

For example that Applying D to some vectors v will be the same as taking the determinant of the coordinate representation of those v, that applying D and getting something non zero to a set of vectors implys those vectors are not a basis, etc.

I know that in the case of two dimensional, we can do this by using the idea that the determinant gives the area of a parallelepiped, etc. And if we define the function to be that that satisfies the above properties then it can be easily shown to be unique.

But in cases when it is not dim 2, since I dont have a general formula for the n vectors , how can this be done? Is it safe to assume that such a function exists and then just show it is unique, or must it be shown that even such a function exists at all?

And say we could just define the function that satisfies those properties. Then how would we show it is unique, etc?

Is it possible to maybe do this problem using matrices? Ie, we can define the determinant on the nxn matrices as our inputs, and somehow use that to prove things?

I have not learned about things called alternating maps.
I am still trying to do this , using advice in answers, is this how it should be approached?

Define a mapping $f: L(V^{n}, \mathbb{F}) \to \mathbb{F}$ by $f \to f(e_1,...,e_n)$, or should it be as $f \to f(x_1,...x_n)$?

Then $f$ is injective as if $f_{1}(e_1,...,e_n)=f_{2}(e_1,...,e_n)$ then would this imply they are equal as how a function acts on a basis completely determines it? I a just really confused. and then If I could show that it is subjective and thus an isomorphism I could say choose that unique f which is the one that gives $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0$ and claim this is the function $D_\beta$ I wanted. But I am having lots of trouble putting it all together.

I still dont understand. It seems like the top answer is getting many vote, but I dont understand it. This is only a first course in linear algebra by the way, so I do not know about many advanced results.
Maybe the answer could rely on sgn function and permutations. Then I could have a general formula
I dont know how in some of the answers we can just simply say suppose D is alternating etc, when this is one of the things I want to prove. That is what is also confusing me. I dont know what we can even start with. Or if we must start from scratch completely.
Looking for advice.

If this cannot be done so easily, I would also be happy to see that if we assume such a function does exist, then at least prove it is unique. Without just saying the determinant is that function and the determinant is unique.

Thank you

Comment: Did you google for the word "determinant"?

Comment: In fact, if you drop the $D(w_1,\ldots,w_n)=1$ condition (and hence have no reason to pick a basis in the first place), the space of such functions form a vector space, and its dimension is $1$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Don't you need antisymmetry for that?

Comment: Do you know about determinants of $n\times n$ matrices or not?

Comment: @RobArthan  Yes I do know about those. How can I use that?

Comment: The determinant looks like a function of the sort that you are looking for.  Now go and prove that it does what you require.

Comment: @RobArthan  What do you mean? That is what I am wondering how to do

Comment: That isn't what your question says.

Comment: I dont understand your comments. Please clarify what you are trying to say

Comment: @RobArthan the question asks to show that the determinant is the *unique* function with these properties

Comment: @Fryie: you imply that I have misunderstood part of the question. Which part did I miss?

Comment: You completely misunderstand the question.. I ask to construct the function that is the determinant not simply show the determinant has those properties.....

Comment: @RobArthan You're implying that the OP should just check that the determinant satifies the given properties. But that's not enough. It has to be shown that there is *a unique* multilinear form with those properties.

Comment: @Fryie: I wrote "now go and prove that [the determinant] does **what you require**".  The OP's stated requirements in the question included the uniqueness.

Comment: @Qualtiy: your question mentions nothing about "construction" and you said in an earlier comment that you knew about determinants. If you are still unable to prove that the determinant has the uniqueness properties that you require, then you have my sympathies.

Comment: It depends what you mean when you say "the determinant" , how does me knowning about determinants of matrices (highschool ussualy) lead you at all to believe I will know anything about the  rigorous proper definition using permutations, which I dont know much about

Comment: @Quality: so ask a more specific question with some context: e.g., "I learnt about determinants at school, but I don't understand the following questions or definitions in my college course on linear algebra ...". (And don't tack on the "Moreover ..." essay.)

Comment: I just want to make sure: Do you know what is the determinant of a $n\times n$ matrix when $n>2$?

Comment: @JohnMa  well I thought I did. But I only knew how to compute it . I didn't know the exact definition but I guess it could be used ( the one with permutations I think)

Comment: So are you happy with an answer that uses determinant in the construction?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean ? I would be happy with the constructing being part of it yes

Comment: I could write an answer, but it seems that it involve inductions and the argument is quite long. More importantly, I don't think it is easier than the existing answer (basically I am just reproving the statement by Augustin). I was writing the answer [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-posts), in the newest answer.

Comment: Meta thread on this question : http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22745/answers-that-do-not-help-but-take-away-attention

Comment: @Quality: Now is the right time to read up on determinants, and in the **rigourous** sense, with a proper definition for $n \times n$-matrices (using permutations or otherwise -- though I don't know how it could be done otherwise). This here: http://hobbes.la.asu.edu/courses/site/442/dets.pdf appears to present the rigorous approach in most of its detail. There's also my http://web.mit.edu/%7Edarij/www/primes2015/sols.pdf (Chapters 5 and 6 leading up to Exercise 24) as a last resort, although it is far from economically written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that
$$
D_\beta(\ldots, \underbrace{w_i+w_j}_{k\text{-th place}},\ldots, \underbrace{w_i+w_j}_{m\text{-th place}},\ldots)=0
$$
because there are two equal vectors. On the other hand, by linearity:
$$
D_\beta(\ldots, {w_i+w_j},\ldots, {w_i+w_j},\ldots)=
D_\beta(\ldots, w_i,\ldots, w_j,\ldots)+
D_\beta(\ldots, w_j,\ldots, w_i,\ldots),
$$
because $D_\beta(\ldots, w_i,\ldots, w_i,\ldots)=D_\beta(\ldots, w_j,\ldots, w_j,\ldots)=0$.
You get then:
$$
D_\beta(\ldots, w_i,\ldots, w_j,\ldots)=
-D_\beta(\ldots, w_j,\ldots, w_i,\ldots),
$$
that is your function, applied to basis vectors, changes of sign whenever you exchange two of its arguments. Together with the request $D_\beta(w_1, \ldots, w_n)=1$ this completely determines the values of $D_\beta$ when its arguments are basis vectors. It follows by linearity that $D_\beta$ is uniquely determined.

To show that applying $D_\beta$ to some vectors will be the same as taking the determinant of the coordinate representation of those vectors, one would need a definition of determinant. My favourite definition of determinant is indeed the same as the definition of $D_\beta$.

Comment: NB: This only proves the uniqueness of the function, not its existence.

Comment: Why shouldn't it exist, as it takes well defined values when its arguments belong to basis $\beta$? From what I've written above it follows that if $\sigma$ is a permutation of $(w_1,\ldots w_n)$ then $D_\beta(\sigma)=\hbox{sgn}(\sigma)$.

Comment: Great answer! This makes sense to me

Comment: @Aretino: If You assume the existence of the sign function, then sure, it proves existence of the determinant.

Answer (score 0):

Each set of vectors $(v_1,...,v_n)$ corresponds to a matrix (the coordinates of $v_k$ are in the column $k$). Using properties 1 and 2, the matrix may be diagonalized without changing the determinant, remember? After that, using property 3, your function is the product of the diagonal terms. The cases with too many zeros give a null determinant, as you should verify to complete the proof.

Example. For $n=2$, $v_1=\sum_{i=1}^2 a_{i1}w_i$, $v_2=\sum_{i=1}^2 a_{i2}w_i$ and $(v_1,v_2)$ corresponds to the matrix 
$$
A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{array}
\right).
$$
The properties 1 and 2 of your function imply that
$$
D\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a_{11} & ca_{11}+a_{12} \\
a_{21} & ca_{21}+a_{22}
\end{array}
\right)=cD\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a_{11} & a_{11} \\
a_{21} & a_{21}
\end{array}
\right)
+D\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{array}
\right)=
D\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{array}
\right)=D(A).
$$
For $a_{11}\neq0$, choose $c$ such that $ca_{11}+a_{12}=0$ and obtain
$$
D\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a_{11} & 0 \\
a_{21} & -\frac{a_{12}a_{21}}{a_{11}}+a_{22}
\end{array}
\right)=D\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{array}
\right).
$$
Now eliminate $a_{21}$ without changing $D(A)$ and obtain
$$
D\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a_{11} & 0 \\
0 & -\frac{a_{12}a_{21}}{a_{11}}+a_{22}
\end{array}
\right)=D(A).
$$
Now use properties 2 and 3 and obtain $D(A)=-a_{12}a_{21}+a_{11}a_{22}$.

Comment: Fixed,thanks. Property 1 is antisymmetry, 2 is linearity and 3 is normalization at the identity matrix (corresponding to (w1,w2)).

Answer (score 0):

There is a complaint [Answers that do not help but take away attention](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22745/answers-that-do-not-help-but-take-away-attention) about the answers here; so I will make this CW and put up with negative comments for a time.

This result is done in exquisite detail in [Greub](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387901107), a book I no longer have.

It is likely done in [Axler](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783319110790). The idea that Axler might include this is somewhat supported by his early [article](http://www.axler.net/DwD.pdf); his book is intended for undergraduates. I do not have a copy.

Answer (score 0):

A few additions to the other answers.

The argument is that the properties can be satisfied, because Determinant relative to the basis $w_i$ satisfies them ; and if a function has those properties it is equal to the Determinant (in the same basis).

The proof of uniqueness needs the fact that the sign of a permutation is well defined, so that different ways of sorting a permutation by transpositions lead to the same $\pm$ sign.

The antisymmetry / skew-symmetry / alternating property (the terminology varies) is usually stated as one of the properties of $D$.  This exercise tries to be cuter or more difficult by making the point that antisymmetry can be deduced from the vanishing when $v_i = v_j$.  In practice, when the vanishing at equal arguments is known, skew-symmetry is also known without having to specially deduce it.